# Configure el-date-picker

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, date-formatting, element-plus

Does someone know, how to configure a el-date-picker in element-plus to set the first day of week.

The docs say it configurable via day.js but not to use configure day.js in element.

I have done this so far.

```js
import de from 'element-plus/es/locale/lang/de';

const i18n = createI18n({
    legacy: false,
    locale: 'de',
    messages: {
        'de': messagesDe
    },
    datetimeFormats: {
        'de': {
            short: {
                year: 'numeric',
                month: '2-digit',
                day: '2-digit'
            },
            long: {
                year: 'numeric',
                month: '2-digit',
                day: '2-digit',
                hour: '2-digit',
                minute: '2-digit',
                second: '2-digit'
            }
        }
    },
});

app.use(ElementPlus, {
   locale: de,
});
app.use(i18n);
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The [workaround described in `dayjs#215`](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/215#issuecomment-471280396) also works for Element Plus.

For example, to set Monday as the first day of the week for the `de` locale, create a `de` object off of `dayjs.Ls`, and set `weekStart=1`:

```js
// main.js
import dayjs from 'dayjs'

dayjs.Ls.de ??= {}
dayjs.Ls.de.weekStart = 1
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-element-plus-first-day-of-week-msa3wn?file=src%2Fmain.js)

[image]

Comment: I am using typescipt I can't do 'dayjs.Ls.de ??= {}'

Comment: Use an `any`-assertion: `(dayjs as any).Ls.de ??= {}`.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked only with this configuration in main.ts:

```
import 'dayjs/locale/ru' // locale will imported inside dayjs.Ls(for datepicker use)
import ru from 'element-plus/lib/locale/lang/ru' // global locale for app
    
app.use(ElementPlus, { locale: ru })
```

[Link to dayjs locale documentation](https://day.js.org/docs/en/installation/typescript#locale-and-plugin-import)